# Segmentation fault when using push_back with 2d vector

Tags: c++, malloc, stdvector, glibc, vscode-debugger

I'm currently trying to build a simple, sequential neural network from scratch in c++ simply for the purpose of learning and general interest. I had it running, though not training particularly well, and a problem began to crop up in a section that was working fine until then.

The issue I am having is whenever I am trying to use push_back() for certain 2-dimensional vectors, I am getting a segmentation fault. This doesn't seem to occur for the first 2-dimensional vector I try to push_back, nor does it occur always.

The relevant code is below:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float>>> weightVec;


...

        void fullyConnectedNetwork::addLayer(nodeLayer* layer, bool initialize, bool addBias)
        {
            
            layerVec.push_back(layer);
            int n = layer->getLength();
            if (layerVec.size() < 2) return;
            int m = layerVec[layerVec.size() - 2]->getLength();
            if (addBias) m++;
            
            if (initialize) {
                std::vector<std::vector<float>> newMatrix(m, std::vector<float>(n, 0));
                initializeWeights(newMatrix, n, m);  //just fills the matrix in with random floats
                weightVec.push_back(newMatrix);         <---segfaults here
            }
            
    
        }
```

The code that calls this function is here:

```
        void fullyConnectedNetwork::addLayer(int size, float (*activationFunction)(float, bool), bool initialize, bool addBias)
        {
            if(addBias && layerVec.size() > 0) layerVec[layerVec.size() - 1]->addBias();
            nodeLayer* layer = new nodeLayer(size, false);
            layer->addActivationFunc(activationFunction);
            addLayer(layer, initialize, addBias);

        }
```

And the code that is used in the main program is here:

```
       fullyConnectedNetwork fcn = fullyConnectedNetwork(.005);
       fcn.addInputLayer(4,  pass);
       fcn.addLayer(3,       sigmoid, true, true);

       fcn.addLayer(4,       sigmoid, true, true); <--- this causes the segfault

       //if I remove the above call to addLayer, the below does not cause a segfault
       //even though the addOutputLayer calls the above addLayer functions
       fcn.addOutputLayer(1, sigmoid, true);  <-- this doesn't cause a segfault

       fcn.addLossFunction(meanSquaredError);
```

Also, when debugging in Vscode, I'm getting this message when it happens:

```
Unable to open 'malloc.c': Unable to read file '/build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/malloc/malloc.c' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/malloc/malloc.c').
```

I've read this message occurs when the debugger can't find the code that is being called. From the call stack, it seems the relevant code where the segmentation fault is happening is in the tcache_get() function in malloc.c:

```
/* Caller must ensure that we know tc_idx is valid and there's
   available chunks to remove.  */
static __always_inline void *
tcache_get (size_t tc_idx)
{
  tcache_entry *e = tcache->entries[tc_idx];
  assert (tc_idx < TCACHE_MAX_BINS);
  assert (tcache->counts[tc_idx] > 0);
  tcache->entries[tc_idx] = e->next;
  --(tcache->counts[tc_idx]);
  e->key = NULL;
  return (void *) e;
}
```

I've tried to replicate the error by setting up similar code to use push_back on other multi-dimensional vectors and they all work fine.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: You could have corrupted the memory long before any of that code is executed.  Please post a [mcve].  Things like this: `fullyConnectedNetwork fcn = fullyConnectedNetwork(.005);` invokes the copy constructor, and we have no idea what `fullyConnectedNetwork` is, or if it has correct copy semantics.  What if you just did: `fullyConnectedNetwork fcn(.005);`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `push_back` itself.

Comment: You're looking at this the wrong way. There's nothing wrong at the point where it crashes, the error has already occurred and the crash is a consequence of that. I would be looking at `initializeWeights` first.

Comment: To add, in `intializeWeights` you create the matrix as `m`and `n`, but in the call, you pass `n` and `m`, in that order.  How about rewriting that function to not pass `m` or `n`, and just use the `size()` function that comes with `std::vector`?  This could be an issue with using extraneous, unnecessary "size" variables, when `vector::size()` is always correct.

Comment: Can you please try a version with smart pointers instead of raw pointers for your used layers/nodes? If possible, use unique pointers here! From the code provided only, I cannot see a direct issue but I suppose, the raw pointer usage itself might be a direct or indirect cause here to your issues.